# ClassNotFoundException: ObjectServiceDescriptor in OSGi

Tags: web-services, maven, osgi, aem, documentum

I am trying to develop a simple java program that calls DFS web services and I get this runtime error:

```
Caused by: com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel.ServiceModelException: Service descriptor class not found: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client.ObjectServiceDescriptor".
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel.JavaBeanTreeFactory.getDescriptor(JavaBeanTreeFactory.java:218)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel.JavaBeanTreeFactory.getModule(JavaBeanTreeFactory.java:41)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory.makeServiceUrl(ServiceFactory.java:332)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory.getRemoteService(ServiceFactory.java:143)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory.getRemoteService(ServiceFactory.java:197)
at info.hartmann.dfs.impl.Handler.init(Handler.java:112)
```

I'm using **maven** to build a project and to install it into the **OSGi container of Adobe CQ5**. I tried this same code in a usual Java application in Eclipse and it worked.

The strange thing for me is that this class ObjectServiceDescriptor  **is in** one of the .jar libraries which I include through maven dependencies. The jar name is **emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar**. If I open my .jar generated by maven, I can see the **emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar** there.

The project compilation goes without any problems, but during runtime I get the error on this line:

```
IObjectService objectService = serviceFactory.getRemoteService(com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client.IObjectService.class, serviceContext,  module, host);
```

My pom.xml is below. As you see, I declare some of the packages as optional in Imported-Packages. If I don't do this, my bundle can be compiled, but cannot be started. Could declaring these packages as optional be the problem?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CXF-example-ievgen</groupId>
    <artifactId>CXF-example-ievgen</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Ievgeng sample bundle</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-bundle</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://192.168.56.101:4502/system/console</slingUrl>
                    <user>user</user>
                    <password>password</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wrap-my-dependency</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wrap</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wrapImportPackage>;</wrapImportPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>info.hartmann.dfs.api</Export-Package>
                        <Private-Package>info.hartmann.dfs.impl

                        </Private-Package>
                        <!-- bundle supplied resource prefixes -->
                        <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>

                        <!-- Do not inline jars, include as jar files -->
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>

                        <!-- use _exportcontents instead of Export-Package to avoid conflict with Embed-Dependency an inline=true -->
                        <!-- <_exportcontents> -->
                        <!-- org.apache.cxf.*;version=${project.version} -->
                        <!-- </_exportcontents> -->

                        <!-- declare optional dependencies -->
                        <Import-Package>
                         com.documentum.fc.client.search;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.fc.common;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.fc.client;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.com;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.ci;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.ucf.*;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.operations.*;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.registry;resolution:=optional,
                         com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.dv.util;resolution:=optional,
                         org.slf4j.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.osgi.*;resolution:=optional,
                         com.emc.documentum.kerberos.*;resolution:=optional,
                         javax.xml.registry.*;resolution:=optional,
                         jp.co.swiftinc.relax.*;resolution:=optional,
                         junit.framework;resolution:=optional,
                         org.apache.xerces.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.apache.xml.*;resolution:=optional,
                         sun.io;resolution:=optional,
                         sun.misc;resolution:=optional,
                         sun.nio.cs;resolution:=optional,
                         sun.security.action;resolution:=optional,
                         com.sun.tools.javadoc;resolution:=optional,
                         org.apache.regexp;resolution:=optional,
                         org.apache.tools.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.apache.xerces.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.apache.xml.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.aspectj.bea.jvm;resolution:=optional,
                         org.eclipse.jface.text;resolution:=optional,
                         org.eclipse.osgi.framework.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.eclipse.osgi.internal.profile;resolution:=optional,
                         org.eclipse.osgi.service.*;resolution:=optional,
                         org.eclipse.osgi.util;resolution:=optional,
                         org.eclipse.update.configurator;resolution:=optional, 
                         *
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>





        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
org.apache.felix
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
maven-scr-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
[1.7.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>scr</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>

                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>



    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <!-- actually it is version 1.1 but i didnt get how to resolve error -->
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2a</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-collaboration</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-admin-services-remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!--<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/emc-admin-services-remote.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-bpm-services-remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-ci-services-remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-dfs-rt-remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-dfs-services-remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>emc-search-services-remote</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.fastinfoset</groupId>
            <artifactId>FastInfoset</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc</groupId>
            <artifactId>http</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb1-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr173_api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
            <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
            <version>20050927</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <!--<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/stax-ex.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
            <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.osgi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-incubator</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.log</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Bundle classpath after installing into OSGi console:

```
    Bundle Classpath    ., sjsxp-1.0.jar, emc-collaboration-1.0.jar, FastInfoset-1.2.jar, 
aspectjrt-1.5.2a.jar,stax-api-1.0.jar,jsr250-api-1.0.jar,activation-1.0.jar, 
resolver-20050927.jar,streambuffer-0.8.jar,jsr181-api-1.0.jar,
jsr173_api-1.0.jar,jaxb1-impl-2.1.4.jar, emc-dfs-rt-remote-1.0.jar,
commons-lang-2.4.jar,commons-io-1.2.jar,stax-ex-1.0.jar,saaj-impl-1.3.3.jar, 
jaxws-rt-2.1.7.jar,xercesImpl-2.5.0.jar,jaxb-api-2.0.jar,mimepull-1.4.jar, 
emc-bpm-services-remote-1.0.jar,emc-search-services-remote-1.0.jar,activation-1.1.jar,http-1.0.jar,
 jaxb-impl-2.1.11.jar,jaxws-api-2.1.jar,emc-ci-services-remote-1.0.jar,
emc-admin-services-remote-1.0.jar, emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar,servlet-api-1.0.jar,saaj-api-1.3.jar
```

My Java code:

```
public void init() throws Exception {
  ContextFactory contextFactory = ContextFactory.getInstance();
  serviceContext = contextFactory.newContext();
  RepositoryIdentity repositoryIdentity = new RepositoryIdentity();

  repositoryIdentity.setRepositoryName(repository);
  repositoryIdentity.setUserName(user);
  repositoryIdentity.setPassword(pass);
  serviceContext.addIdentity(repositoryIdentity);

  ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.getInstance();
//ERROR is thrown here:
  objectService = serviceFactory.getRemoteService(IObjectService.class, serviceContext,  module, host);
  queryService = serviceFactory.getRemoteService(IQueryService.class, serviceContext,  module, host);
  }
```

I've seen a similar problem here: https://community.emc.com/thread/82798 but the solution provided there didn't help me. I tried

- Changing JRE version to higher than 1.5
- Making sure make sure that I am creating a class of type com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client.IObjectService (and not com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.impl.IObjectService).
- Trying with the more fully parameterized version of getRemoteService which will remove any ambiguties with the call.
- And lots of other things, like installing all the external jars in a separate bundle and then importing them.

It looks like a maven dependency problem, but I can't figure it out, as I included all the .jars in my project which I used in my Eclipse project, so it should work the same, shouldn't it?

I appreciate any help.

EDIT:
I tried changing export-packages to:
info.hartmann.dfs.api, com.emc.documentum.*
In other words, I tried exporting all the documentum packages. The above listed error dissapeared, but I got a new one:

```
Caused by: com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel.ServiceModelException: Service descriptor file not found: "services-core-service-model.xml".
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel.JavaBeanTreeFactory.getModuleByName(JavaBeanTreeFactory.java:65)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.servicemodel.JavaBeanTreeFactory.getModule(JavaBeanTreeFactory.java:42)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory.makeServiceUrl(ServiceFactory.java:332)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory.getRemoteService(ServiceFactory.java:143)
at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory.getRemoteService(ServiceFactory.java:197)
at info.hartmann.dfs.impl.Handler.init(Handler.java:112)
```

Unfortunatelly, I don't even know if it moves me one step further or one step behind.

Comment: Do you get the same error on the next line, using IQueryService?

Comment: Also, strange that it is looking for `...client.ObjectServiceDescriptor` when you are using the remote .jars?  Have you tried including both?

Comment: @unicron, on the next line, using IQueeryService I get error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client.QueryServiceDescriptor"

Comment: @unicron, which ones do you mean when you say both? I am including all these jars emc-dfs-rt-remote-1.0.jar, emc-bpm-services-remote-1.0.jar, emc-search-services-remote-1.0.jar, emc-ci-services-remote-1.0.jar, emc-admin-services-remote-1.0.jar, emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar

Comment: Yeah, what I'm saying is that it seems to be looking for the *client* class, but you are including only the remote .jar files.  That is why it is failing.

Comment: @unicron, the thing is .jar emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar contains this client class. Here is the content of this .jar https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3396301/jarcontent.txt But thanks to you I understood that I made a stupid and probably popular mistake. I didn't OSGify this jar, so it didn't export any packages.   It didn't solve my task, because other problems and exception (probably dependency problems) followed, but at least this problem is solved.

Comment: The `services-core-service-model.xml` file should be in `emc-dfs-services.jar`.  I'm not sure if it exists in `emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar` or not.  Can you verify?

Comment: @unicron, There is a file **services-core-service-model.xml** in **emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar**. But I don't have jar **emc-dfs-services.jar**, so I can't say about emc-dfs-services. Here is the content of the **emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar** https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3396301/jarcontent.txt

Comment: At this point I'm just not familiar enough with maven and osgi to be much help.  It seems like there is still an issue with the classpath resolution.  What if you explicitly put emc-dfs-services-remote-1.0.jar at the beginning of the export?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user bundle is missing the wiring to `com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client.ObjectServiceDescriptor`. Just being in the classpath is not enough

Confirm that the `JavaBeanTreeFactory` bundle imports the package `com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client`